# Incorrect result printed when multiplying numbers in C

Tags: c, math

I've recently begun using C and I'm having some problems with the simple arithmetic operation of just being able to multiply two numbers.

Initially, I tried to print the result of 8 * 2 to a file. Currently this outputs 16. Next, I multiplied what I really wanted 8*0.000000123456789. Here is my code:

```
            fprintf( fp2, "%d\n", (long double)(8*0.000000123456789));
```

The result outputted to the file is : **-1086490624**. Whereas really it should have been : **0.000000987654312**. I intentionally type-casted the arithmetic as a long double to prevent any overflow. Not doing anything and using:

```
            fprintf( fp2, "%d\n", (8*0.000000123456789));
```

Yields **1719134127**, again having no relation to the actual value of **0.000000987654312**

Any suggestions please?

Comment: If you ever want to avoid overflow, the cast should be performed on one of the *operands*, not on the result of the operation.

Comment: @Ken: Or rather, the operand should be specified with the correct literal!

Comment: I will also point out that when you do operations with floating point numbers you may get rounding errors so when you do get it to print out it may not be exactly what you thing it should be.

Comment: @murgatroid99: You may just have prevented this week's "why aren't my floats equal" question :-) Tip for the OP: There are tons of questions and answers about floating point numbers on SO, so please feel free to browse around.

Comment: Thanks all. Really informative replies. I did have a look at the other posts around btw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that your problem is that you're using the `%d` placeholder in `printf`, which only prints out `int` values.  Since you're passing a `double` or `long double` to `printf`, you probably want to use another modifier in place of `%d`.  For example, if you're printing out a `double`, you could use the `%f` modifier:

```
fprintf( fp2, "%f\n", (8*0.000000123456789));
```

The more technical reason that you're getting random values back instead of anything close to the original value is that when you try printing something with `printf`, the function tries interpreting the bits of the argument in a way that depends on what specifier you use.  Since floating-point values like `float`s and `double`s are usually represented internally in the computer using a completely different encoding than integers (often as [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) values rather than [signed two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)), the results of trying to take bits of a `float` or `double` and representing them as an integer are usually meaningless.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yikes, should have looked at digging into the fprintf function further. It does print the right value now, but it truncates a lot of decimal places. I will do some research on figuring that out as well as how to get signed number multiplication to work as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Got the right precision I wanted as well, by just reading up on printf : fprintf( fp2, "%1.9f\n", (float)(8*0.000000123456789));. Thanks again!

Comment: @c0d3rz: That cast is pointless -- variadic arguments promote all floats to doubles, so you might as well stick with doubles from the start.

Answer (score 8):

Suggestion 1: Read the manual for `printf`.

Suggestion 2: Repeat to yourself over and over: "**printf is not typesafe.** I promise to be extra careful when using it."

Suggestion 3: Always always enable and take to heart all compiler warnings. This would have caught it right away.

Answer: You promise `printf` that you will provide an `int` by saying `%d`. However, in reality you provide a `long double`. The result of this failure to keep your promise is *undefined behaviour*. To print a long double, say `%Lf` (cf. (1)).

Comment: ... which usually shows up as `printf` interpreting the first `sizeof(int)` bytes of your `long double` as they were an `int`. (+1, by the way)

Comment: @Matteo: Indeed. If you had a mind, you could work out exactly why you see what you do. I did that once though, so I've done my due :-)

Comment: @Matteo: Actually, with long doubles you have the extra fun of 12 or 16 byte padding, and I'm not sure at which end that's applied. Happy printing :-)

Comment: it's always nice to discover that things are even worse than you thought. :-)